# It is a good idea for store likes in redis?

Tags: mongodb, redis

In my application I use **mongodb** for storing data.

But, I can not embed some relationships such as `likes` in documents, because, it is limited by 16 mb.

I can store relationships, in another collection, in **mongodb** or in **redis**.

What will be better, and why?

Answer (score 1):

How about store `likes` in another collection in MongoDB.

```
{
    _id: xxx,
    like_from: "somebody",
    like_to: "something"
}
```

you can create index on `like_from` and `like_to` fields to speed up the query of `all things that somebody likes` and `all person that like something`.